# Convertir tipo de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008 R2 quiero hacer lo siguiente en un JOIN

```
JOIN tabla ON campo1 = TRY_CAST(campo2 AS INT)
```

campo2 es de tipo `varchar` campo1 es de tipo `int`

> Nota: en el campo `varchar` tengo valores `Null` y `vacios`

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: como lo podes solucionar? porque? da un error?

Comment: ¿Cuales son los tipos de datos involucrados?

Comment: @gbianchi creo que TRY_CAST no está disponible en esa versión.

Comment: la pregunta esta muy incompleta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Advertencia

Comienzo diciendo que no tengo SQL 2008 a mano y que, siendo el 2021 mientras escribo esta respuesta, **desaconsejo totalmente su uso** y recomiendo urgir a cualquier persona de la que dependa la decisión de continuar usándolo a que cambie de idea. La base de datos, que data de hace más de 13 años (en informática eso es equivalente a varias eras) no tiene soporte desde hace aproximadamente dos años, lo que la hace particularmente vulnerable en estos tiempos, además que sus características están bastante por debajo de lo que se espera de una base de datos hoy día.

### Respuesta

Puedes valerte de la función `cast` para hacer la comparación. Dado que pueden existir valores con los que esta función de error, primero hay que excluir todas las filas que podrían dar algún problema al ejecutar la conversión, y es allí donde está el reto.

Para ello, pondremos una serie de condiciones **antes** de realizar la conversión, de manera que esta nunca llegue a ejecutarse para las filas excluidas, evitando el error.

Lo que dejo a continuación es *un ejemplo* de lo primero que me viene a la mente, según mi experiencia, pero algo sólido o robusto puedes obtenerlo solo con la experiencia y dependerá de qué tan diverso sea el conjunto de datos sobre el que lo apliques.

- Lo primero que usaré es la función `isNumeric()`, que de entrada nos excluirá todas las cadenas que no puedan convertirse a un número, y dejará solo aquellas que puedan convertirse, tanto a entero, como a números de coma flotante.
- Luego, hay algunas cadenas que aún serían problemáticas, por ejemplo:

  - Las que contengan el separador decimal. Incluiré el punto y la coma para hacer amplio el soporte.
  - Las que tengan notación científica, que contendrían la letra `e`.

Entonces, nos queda:

```
JOIN tabla ON campo1 = case
                         when     IsNumeric(Campo2) = 1
                              and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
                              and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
                              and charindex('e', Campo2) = 0
                              and charindex('E', Campo2) = 0 
                         then
                           cast(campo2 AS INT) 
                       end
```

Sobra decir que la ejecución de esta consulta no es óptima, ya que no puede basarse en índices y obliga, a todos los registros exitosos, a pasar por todas las condiciones del `join`.

Quizás una mejor alternativa sea convertir el número a cadena, por lo que no hay que dejar de considerar esa posibilidad, teniendo en cuenta que, en este caso se pueden excluir algunas coincidencias que entrarían si se usa el primer enfoque, por ejemplo, cadenas que tengan ceros a la izquierda.

```
JOIN tabla ON cast(campo1 as varchar(50)) = campo2
```

### Edición

Gracias a Luis Cazares y Pablo Gutierrez por sus aportes en comentarios, he actualizado la respuesta para utilizar una expresión que será más robusta y no fallará, el optimizador haga lo que haga.

Mi respuesta original tenía esta expresión:

```
JOIN tabla ON     IsNumeric(Campo2) = 1
              and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
              and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
              and charindex('e', Campo2) = 0
              and charindex('E', Campo2) = 0
              and campo1 = cast(campo2 AS INT)
```

Que está en riesgo de fallar ya que SQL, al ser un lenguaje declarativo, no garantiza el orden de ejecución de las expresiones.

Comment: Lamento arruinar una buena respuesta, pero no hay ninguna garantía de que las otras condiciones se ejecuten antes de la comparación entre ambas columnas. Para hacer eso, tendría que usarse un CASE.  De cualquier forma, creo que es mejor convertir a cadena. Aunque lo mejor sería corregir la base de datos.

Comment: @Luis, ¿tienes forma de soportar lo que afirmas? En realidad yo he asumido lo contrario, ahora estoy haciendo una búsqueda para aprender realmente como funciona, por eso la pregunta.

Comment: @jachguate TRY_CAST no esta soportado en SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Pedro, debí poner `cast`, ya la respuesta está actualizada.

Comment: Podría tratar de generar el error, pero el problema es que todo puede funcionar correctamente hasta que un día decide fallar. Si te fijas, en la documentación no existe nada que indique que las condiciones se ejecutan en el orden en que se escriben.

Comment: @jachguate Agregue un comentario al hilo principal

Comment: @Pedro, mi respuesta se mantiene intacta después del comentario. ¿Crees que deba variar en algo?

Comment: @Luis, hasta ahora no he visto un lenguajes o motores que no ejecute condiciones unidas por operadores lógicos _en orden_ (obviamente respetando la precedencia de los operadores). Esto es lo que permite _cortocircuitar_ las operaciones y detener la ejecución tan pronto como se sabe la respuesta. Estoy tratando de idear una forma de confirmar el orden en que se ejecutan, poder hacer `print` dentro de una función vendría genial ahora...

Comment: @jachguate Era solo para agregar más información.

Comment: Llamó mi atención el primer comentario de @LuisCazares y me puse a investigar porque siempre he asumido que el orden de evaluación de las condiciones lo elige el manejador basado en indices y estadísticas. Comparto [este](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-t-sql-expression-short-circuiting) artículo que encontré por si les resulta de interés. (está en inglés)

Comment: Gracias pablo, justo lo estaba leyendo ya...

Comment: Tal vez no lo expresé de la mejor manera, pero mi idea era muy similar a lo Gianluca (Spaguetti DBA) explica a detalle. La única forma de tener certeza del orden en que se ejecutan las comparaciones en SQL Server es con un CASE. El resto puede funcionar o puede que no. Y como lo dije antes, puede que de un momento a otro falle porque el optimizador de consultas cambió de opinión sobre cual condición evaluar primero.

Comment: @Pedro, hice un cambio en la respuesta, sugiero que uses la nueva expresión para hacer el join.

Comment: @Luis, he editado la respuesta, gracias por el aporte. Un cordial saludo.

Comment: @Pablo, he editado la respuesta, gracias por el aporte. Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Gracias a ti por los aportes, siempre aprendo algo de tus respuestas.