# Dando formato a un campo resultado SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008
Deseo aplicar el valor de decimales al campo resultado

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE (resultado varchar(50),campo1 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table1 (resultado,campo1)
VALUES ('0.4532','0.5')
    , ('1.2','1')
    , ('2.34432','0.001')
    , ('2.87654','1.0')
--  , ('<1.8', '--');


select resultado, case 
when d.num = 0 then floor(resultado)
--when d.num = '--' then resultado
else round(resultado, d.num-1,1) 
end
from @table1 cross apply (select charindex('.', reverse(campo1))) d(num)
```

Resultado

```
 resultado                                          
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
0.4532                                             0.4
1.2                                                1
2.34432                                            2.344
2.87654                                            2.8
```

Hay un detalle cuando descomente esta linea de código  `('<1.8', '--');` si campo1 = -- el valor del resultado queda como esta <1.8 no sufre cambios.

Lo he intentado agregando un `when d.num = '--' then resultado` pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar '--' al tipo de datos int.
```

Probare con `substring` para ver si comienza con `<`

Como resultado espero lo siguiente

```
resultado
0.4
1
2.344
2.8
<1.8
```

Comment: ¿Por qué esperas 2.8 en la última fila, si el valor aproxima a 2.9?

Comment: @jachguate no debo de redondear actualice la pregunta y actualice el código donde me da 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que todo está en campos de cadenas de caracteres, y tomando en cuenta que no quires redondear, creo que el mejor enfoque que se puede tener es trabajar con las cadenas de caracteres directamente.

Las piezas del rompecabezas son:

- `IsNumeric()`, ya que no quieres *tocar* las cadenas que no representen números, podemos valernos de esta función para determinar si una cadena representa un número o no. Estoy asumiendo que las cadenas tienen datos más o menos limpios, si no es así, te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/461349/21), donde se trata más a profundidad el uso de esta función.
- `ltrim()` y `rtrim()` para eliminar caracteres blancos que pueden estar al principio o al final de las cadenas e interferir en la producción de resultados correctos.
- `len()`, para determinar la longitud de una cadena
- `charindex()` para determinar la posición de una sub-cadena en una cadena, en este caso, el punto decimal.

El resto de la idea es determinar si lo que contienen las columnas son números, cual es la posición del punto decimal en cada una y luego hacer algo de aritmética para *recortar* la cadena del *resultado* de manera que refleje la misma cantidad de decimales que las del `campo1`

Mi propuesta se basa en el uso de CTE's que, a mi manera de ver, hace más legible la consulta, ya que permite asignar un nombre de columna a un cálculo y en queries subsigientes referirse a dicho cálculo por el nombre asignado. Se puede lograr lo mismo sin el uso de CTE's, ese ejercicio queda para el lector si está interesado.

El primer CTE, `Base1`, limpia los campos de posibles espacios y determina si su contenido es numérico.

El segundo CTE, `Base2`, determina además la longitud de la cadena de resultado y la posición del punto decimal en las cadenas que representan números. Para las que no representan números, devuelve `null` en la posición decimal.

La consulta final recorta la cadena del resultado al largo correspondiente, solo cuando ambos campos contienen números. De lo contrario, deja la cadena original (sin espacios).

En código, luce así:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (resultado varchar(50),campo1 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table1 (resultado,campo1)
VALUES ('0.4532','0.5')
    , ('1.2','1')
    , ('2.34432','0.001')
    , ('2.87654','1.0')
    , ('<1.8', '--');

with
Base1 as (
SELECT   ltrim(rtrim(resultado)) resultado
       , ltrim(rtrim(campo1)) campo1
       , isNumeric(ltrim(rtrim(Campo1))) IsNumericCampo1
       , isNumeric(ltrim(rtrim(Resultado))) IsNumericResultado
  from @table1
)
,
Base2 as (
select *
       , len(resultado) lenResultado
       , case 
           when IsNumericCampo1 = 1 then 
             case when charindex('.', Campo1) = 0 then 0 else len(Campo1) - charindex('.', Campo1) end 
         end decimalesCampo1
       , case 
           when IsNumericResultado = 1 then 
             case when charindex('.', Resultado) = 0 then 0 else len(Resultado) - charindex('.', Resultado) end 
         end decimalesResultado
  from Base1
)
select   Resultado ResultadoOriginal
       , Campo1
       , case
           when IsNumericResultado = 1 and IsNumericCampo1 = 1 then 
             substring(Resultado, 1, LenResultado - DecimalesResultado + DecimalesCampo1 - iif(DecimalesCampo1 = 0 and DecimalesResultado > 0, 1, 0))
           else Resultado
         end Resultado
  from Base2;
```

Y produce la siguiente salida:

```
ResultadoOriginal  Campo1    Resultado
------------------ --------- ----------
0.4532             0.5       0.4
1.2                1         1
2.34432            0.001     2.344
2.87654            1.0       2.8
<1.8               --        <1.8

(5 rows affected)
```